# Follow up (merging single digit ints into one number)

Tags: java, arraylist, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield

Here is the code with the GUI and revision to the for loop I created earlier. Every time the user pushes the one button I am hoping the textfield to reflect that the button was pressed.

If the user presses the 1 button once: 1 is pushed onto the field.
If the user presses the 1 button twice: 11 is pushed onto the field. 
... and so on.

Instead, the program crashes the second time the button is pressed. Can somebody tell me what is going wrong?

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;

 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.lang.Math;

 public class poopy
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        //frame width and height
       final int FRAME_WIDTH = 290;
       final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 210;

       //created frame and panel. Panel layout is taken away from the flow layout.
       JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
       myFrame.setTitle("Simple Calculator");
       myFrame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
       JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
       myPanel.setLayout(null);

       //TextField on Simple Calculator
       final JTextField myText = new JTextField();
       myText.setSize(250,30);
       myText.setLocation(10,10);

       final JButton oneButton = new JButton("1");
       oneButton.setSize(50,50);
       oneButton.setLocation(10,102);

       //makes panel visible and close when the 'x' is hit
       myFrame.add(myPanel);
       myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       myFrame.setVisible(true);

       myPanel.add(oneButton);
       myPanel.add(myText);

       class CalculatorListener implements ActionListener
       {
           ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           double x=0;
           int k = 0;

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {

               if(e.getSource() == oneButton)
               {
                   num.add(1);

                   for(int i = num.size() -1; i>=0; i--)
                   {
                       x = num.get(k) * Math.pow(10,i);
                       k=k+1;
                   }

                   myText.setText(" " + String.valueOf(x));

               }
           }
       }

       //buttons are given life
       CalculatorListener myListener = new CalculatorListener();
       oneButton.addActionListener(myListener);
   }

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific exception thrown at a specific line of code when the program "crashes"?  That would probably tell you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`k` is never being reset to zero, so the second time through the loop you're starting at an index that's out of range in `num`. Additionally, `x` is being reset with every time through the loop instead of what I assume your intent is - to add to `x` with each pass through the `for` loop(It will then need to be reset when the button is pressed again)

Try this:

```
if(e.getSource() == oneButton)
{
  num.add(1);
  k = 0;

  for(int i = num.size() -1; i>=0; i--)
  {
    x = num.get(k) * Math.pow(10,i);
    k=k+1;
  }

  myText.setText(" " + String.valueOf(x));

}
```

Comment: I understand about x. but I am confused on what I am supposed to do with k. When I place k underneath the getSource if statement, I get an error when I press the one button once.

Comment: I figured it out without using the arrayList, i just set a double variable and everytime a number button is pressed that double would be multiplied by 10 and then the appropriate number would be added on to the end.